# Binary OR on [Flags] Enumeration Elements - Why is simple addition of Flags not allowed?

Tags: c#, enums, bitwise-operators, enumeration, flags

```
[Flags]
public enum EyeColors
{
    None = 0,
    Blue = 1 << 0,
    Cyan = 1 << 1,
    Brown = 1 << 2,
    Black = 1 << 3,
    Green = 1 << 4,
    Browngreen = 2 | 4
    // Browngreen = Brown | Green
}
```

While

```
Browngreen = 2 | 4
Browngreen = Brown | Green
```

does work

```
Browngreen = 6
```

does not. The evaluation of a test like

```
EyeColors.Browngreen == (EyeColors.Brown | EyeColors.Green);
```

evaluates to false in cases wheren *Browngreen* is set to 6.

---

This puzzles me. The way I understand the binary or is that the flagged bits get added so that:

0100 : 4 
0010 : 2 
**0110 : 6**

So why doesn't it work when I just set?

```
Browngreen = 6;
```

Comment: Is brown 1 << 3 (**8**)or is brown somehow 4 (which is 1 << 2, which is not in your enum)?

Comment: Why do you expect `&` and `|` to work the same way? 2&4=0, whereas 2|4=6.

Comment: Setting `Browngreen = 2 & 4` will _not_ work correctly (the expression `2 & 4` evaluates to `0`...you really want `2 | 4`, just like `Brown | Green`). You need to post a question with an actual [mcve] that reproduces the problem. Though, based on what you've written so far, it'll be a simple typographical error, of no use whatsoever to the Stack Overflow community or corpus. You should change your test to `EyeColors.Brown | EyeColors.Green`; what you have now will fail except when you set `Browngreen = 2 & 4`.

Comment: @oerkelens thanks, i had a typo there

Comment: @PeterDuniho oh, sorry i thought i fomulated my question well. I'll make some changes. Or is it better to just delete the question?

Comment: its still a typo. or wrong assumption, at least. its because 1 << 4 is not the same as 4. (1 shiftleft 4 is 16, 1 shiftleft 2 is 4, 16 | 4 == 20)

Comment: I think OP has not understood 1 << 2 is 4, and 1 << 4 is 16. Please see my example below.

Comment: @dlatikay perfect, thats the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine flags, you need to use the | operator.
Think it as binary : 10000 & 00100 will give 0 (None), but 10000 | 00100 will give 10100, hence 20, as you expect.

Also, in your "All" case, the "None" flag has no meaning, I removed it.

Here's a working example :

```
[Flags]
public enum EyeColors
{
    None = 0,
    Blue = 1 << 0, // 1
    Cyan = 1 << 1, // 2
    Brown = 1 << 2, // 4
    Black = 1 << 3, // 8
    Green = 1 << 4, // 16
    Browngreen = Brown | Green,
    All = Blue | Green | Brown | Black | Cyan
}

void Main()
{
    EyeColors eyeColors = EyeColors.Brown;
    Console.WriteLine(eyeColors + " (" + (int)eyeColors + ")");

    eyeColors = EyeColors.Brown & EyeColors.Green;
    Console.WriteLine(eyeColors + " (" + (int)eyeColors + ")"); // None

    eyeColors = EyeColors.Brown | EyeColors.Green;  
    Console.WriteLine(eyeColors + " (" + (int)eyeColors + ")"); // Brown green

    eyeColors = (EyeColors)20;
    Console.WriteLine(eyeColors + " (" + (int)eyeColors + ")"); // Brown green also

    eyeColors = EyeColors.All;
    Console.WriteLine(eyeColors + " (" + (int)eyeColors + ")");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My initial question remains: why cant you set the enumeration element Browngreen to 6 instead of "Brown | Green"?

Shouldn't "Brown|Green" and "6" mean the same in this context?

Comment: Brown|Green is NOT 6, it's 20. See the comment I added in enum.

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope you'll find it easier to understand. The example is working, you can execute it in linqpad or build it as a regular C# program, as you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, you solved the problem. I made a couple of mistakes and missassumptions there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help ! If it's easier for you, keep in mind that you can also just assign your enum members with regular integers : Blue = 1,
    Cyan = 2,
    Brown = 4,
    Black = 8... Etc. It will give the same result but it's easier to read if you're not yet used to binary operators !